# Create dynamic table in php with mysql data

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, html-table

I would to like to create a dynamic table that the rows and columns of the table depends on the data in mysql data. Please see below my codes.

```
<?php
require "connect/db.php"; 

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(level) level, shelf_no, bin_id FROM location_bin WHERE rack_id =1 GROUP BY shelf_no");
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

$col = $res['level']; //col
$row = $res['shelf_no']; //rows

echo "<table border='1'>";
$i = 0;
    while ($i < $col){
        if ($i==$col){
        echo "<tr>";

    }
        echo "<td>".$res['bin_id']."</td>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

What I want is to display A-1-01 up to A-1-06 in the first row then A-2-01 to A-2-03 on the second row. Note that the data is dynamic.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/creating-dynamic-table/211446.   You should try this ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code . It works. change db.php path as your system path.

```
require "db.php";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT level, shelf_no, bin_id FROM location_bin ORDER BY shelf_no asc, level asc ');

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
$i=0;

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $row=$res['shelf_no'];
    if ($i < $row){
            $i=$row;
        echo "</tr><tr>";

    }

    echo "<td>".$res['bin_id']."</td>";



    }


echo "</table>";

?>
```